# Query to return connecting flights given source and destination

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I have a table called "Flights" that stores the source and destination of a flight.  Say you have A -> B and B -> C in a table, and you give the source as 'A' and destination as 'C', the query should return the path between these two A - > B, B -> C. I have tried this query:

```
$result = $mysqli -> query(
        "SELECT *
        FROM Flights a
        JOIN Flights b
        ON a.Destination = b.Source
        AND '{$source}' = a.Source
        AND '{$destination}' = b.Destination");
```

As a side note: I'm using mysqli in PHP.  I have done this query in the mysql console and it returns everything I need.  But if I ran this query in PHP on the example table I gave it would return B -> C only.  Any ideas where I went wrong?  I think it could have to do with the PHP string formatting.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['source'])){
$source = $_POST['source'];
}

if(isset($_POST['destination'])){
$destination = $_POST['destination'];
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "Airport Tracking";
$table ="Flights";
$flag = 0;

// Create connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['source']) && isset($_POST['destination'])){
$columns= $mysqli -> query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");

$sql = "SELECT *
FROM Flights a
JOIN Flights b
ON a.Destination = b.Source
AND {$source} = a.Source
AND {$destination} = b.Destination";

echo "$sql";

$result = $mysqli -> query($sql);


if($result == FALSE){
echo "<br><b>Incorrect input</b>";
$flag = 1;
}
else if($result->num_rows == 0){
echo "<br><b>Returned no results</b>";
$flag = 1;
}

}

$array = array();
$i = 0;

if(isset($_POST['source']) && $flag == 0){
// Display results
echo "<table>";
echo "<thead><tr>";
while ($row = $columns -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
echo "<th>" .$row['Field']. "</th>";
$array[] = $row['Field'];
}
echo "</tr></thead>";

while ($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
echo "<tr>";
while ($i < sizeof($array)) {
    echo "<td>" .utf8_encode($row[$array[$i]]). "</td>";
    $i++;
}
echo "</tr>";
$i = 0;
}
echo "</table>";
}



$mysqli->close();
?>
```

That is my PHP code.  I apologize because I know indenting is incorrect.

Comment: From reading over the query I don't see anything that would be wrong. Try storing the query in a variable and echo'ing the string. Double check that it looks right with the variables and run that query on the mysql console. You should get the same result. Also, just an FYI, you should really parameterize those variables.

Comment: I just echoed out the query as a string and it looked the same as when I did it in the console.  I suspect it has to do with how I am printing out the rows. I will edit the original post with the rest of my PHP code.